Issues Mounting Windows NTFS Partitions Automatically After Upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04
Description of the Problem
I recently upgraded my laptop from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04. Since the upgrade, I've encountered issues accessing my Windows partitions (Windows-SSD and Windows-HDD) from Ubuntu. These partitions used to mount automatically when I clicked on them in the file manager in Ubuntu 22.04. Now, after the upgrade, I'm getting errors when I try to access them through the GUI.
The specific error message I receive when I try to mount these partitions from the GUI reads:
Unable to access location

Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/mahmoud/Windows-HDD: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

The same error appears for /dev/nvme0n1p3 (the SSD partition). The problem persists whether I try to mount the HDD or SSD.
System Configuration

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 (Upgraded from 22.04)
Windows Partitions: Windows-SSD (/dev/nvme0n1p3) and Windows-HDD (/dev/sda2)
Dual Boot Setup: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 24.04

Steps Taken to Troubleshoot and Attempt to Resolve the Issue

Checked Windows State:

Booted into Windows to ensure that Fast Startup and Hibernation were turned off.
Ran powercfg /h off in Windows Command Prompt to disable hibernation.
Disabled Fast Startup via Control Panel > Power Options > Choose what the power buttons do > Unchecked "Turn on fast startup."
Ran chkdsk on both C: (SSD) and D: (HDD) to ensure there were no filesystem errors.


Verified Filesystem Status with ntfsfix:

Booted back into Ubuntu and ran ntfsfix on both partitions:
sudo ntfsfix /dev/nvme0n1p3
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2


ntfsfix indicated that the SSD was in a hibernated state, while the HDD showed no signs of hibernation but still produced an error during mounting.


Manual Mounting of Partitions:

Tried manually mounting the partitions using the ntfs-3g driver:
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o force /dev/nvme0n1p3 /media/mahmoud/Windows-SSD
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o force /dev/sda2 /media/mahmoud/Windows-HDD


The manual mounting worked without issues. However, clicking on the drives in the GUI still resulted in errors.


Modified /etc/fstab for Auto-Mount:

Updated /etc/fstab to mount the partitions at boot:
/dev/nvme0n1p3  /media/mahmoud/Windows-SSD  ntfs-3g  defaults,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,users,x-gvfs-show  0  0
/dev/sda2       /media/mahmoud/Windows-HDD  ntfs-3g  defaults,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,users,x-gvfs-show  0  0


The x-gvfs-show option was added to make the partitions visible in the GNOME Files application.
Ran sudo mount -a to mount all filesystems defined in /etc/fstab.
Despite this, when clicking on the drives in the GUI after unmounting them, they still wouldn't remount automatically, and I continued getting the same error messages.
Additionally, after adding the entries to /etc/fstab, the disk icons in the GNOME Files sidebar became unresponsive. Clicking on them did not trigger the mount as it did in the previous version (22.04).


Reloaded Systemd Configuration:

After modifying /etc/fstab, I ran:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload


This was to ensure that systemd used the latest /etc/fstab changes, but it did not resolve the GUI mounting issue.


Installed/Reinstalled ntfs-3g:

Reinstalled the NTFS driver to ensure there were no driver issues:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall ntfs-3g


No improvement in mounting behavior was observed after reinstallation.



Current State

Manual Mounting Works: I can successfully mount the partitions using the mount command in the terminal with the ntfs-3g driver.
GUI Fails to Mount: Clicking the partitions in GNOME Files shows the error ("wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock..."). This behavior was not present before the upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.
Auto-Mount Not Functioning as Expected: In Ubuntu 22.04, these partitions used to auto-mount when accessed through the GUI without any issues. Now, they require manual intervention.
Icons Unresponsive in GNOME Files: After adding the entries in /etc/fstab, the disk icons for Windows-SSD and Windows-HDD in the GNOME sidebar became unresponsive. Clicking them no longer triggers an attempt to mount the drives, and no prompt is shown.

Additional Observations

The dmesg command shows repeated warnings that the NTFS volumes are dirty and recommends using chkdsk in Windows.
Despite running chkdsk and disabling hibernation, the problem persists, suggesting an underlying compatibility or configuration issue introduced with Ubuntu 24.04.

Request for Assistance
I would appreciate assistance in understanding why these issues are happening only after the upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04. Specifically:

Why do these NTFS partitions no longer auto-mount properly through the GUI, as they did in 22.04?
Is there a configuration change or compatibility issue with the newer version of Ubuntu that affects NTFS mounting?
What additional steps can I take to resolve this and restore the seamless auto-mount functionality I had before?
Why do the disk icons in GNOME Files become unresponsive after modifying /etc/fstab? How can I restore the previous functionality where clicking on the icons would auto-mount the drives?

Thank you in advance for your help. I look forward to resolving this issue and restoring normal functionality to my dual-boot setup.

Do not know details, but new ntfs3 driver is now standard, but some have reported issues. https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/ntfs3.html
Merged two years ago with Linux 5.15 (22.04) with the "NTFS3" driver developed by Paragon Software   Do not do install ntfsprogs as on newer versions it uninstalls ntfs-3g And have seen a few posts on issues with new ntfs3 driver. So which driver are you actually using? And have you tried both?

Step-by-Step Guide to Fix "Dirty" NTFS Partitions and Enable Mounting in Ubuntu
I encountered an issue where my NTFS partitions wouldn't mount in Ubuntu because they were marked as "dirty." After some research and troubleshooting, I found a solution by using Windows' chkdsk utility and adjusting certain system settings. Here's how I fixed the problem:

A. Boot into Windows

Restart Your Computer

I clicked on the Start menu, selected Power, and chose Restart.


Select Windows from the Boot Menu

Since I have a dual-boot setup, I made sure to select Windows from the boot options to access the Windows environment.




B. Run chkdsk on the Affected Partitions

Open Command Prompt as Administrator

I pressed Win + X and selected Command Prompt (Admin) or Windows PowerShell (Admin) to open it with administrative privileges.


Identify the Drive Letters

I checked which drive letters corresponded to /dev/sda2 and /dev/nvme0n1p3. Typically, these were my C: and D: drives, but I confirmed by opening File Explorer.


Run chkdsk

For each affected partition, I executed the following command:
chkdsk X: /f


Example:
chkdsk C: /f
chkdsk D: /f


Explanation:

The /f flag tells chkdsk to fix any errors on the disk.
Note: If the drive is in use (like the system drive), chkdsk prompted me to schedule the check on the next restart. I typed Y and pressed Enter.






Allow chkdsk to Complete

After scheduling the check, I restarted my computer. During the boot process, chkdsk ran automatically and fixed the detected issues.




C. Disable Fast Startup and Hibernate
Fast Startup and Hibernate can prevent NTFS partitions from being cleanly unmounted, causing them to remain in a "dirty" state. Disabling these features ensures that Windows fully shuts down, allowing Ubuntu to mount the partitions without issues.
1. Disable Fast Startup

Open Control Panel

I pressed Win + R, typed control, and pressed Enter to open the Control Panel.


Navigate to Power Options

I went to Hardware and Sound > Power Options.


Choose What the Power Buttons Do

I clicked on "Choose what the power buttons do" on the left sidebar.


Change Settings

I clicked "Change settings that are currently unavailable" to modify the shutdown settings.


Uncheck Fast Startup

Under Shutdown settings, I unchecked "Turn on fast startup (recommended)".


Save Changes

I clicked "Save changes" to apply the new settings.



2. Disable Hibernate (Optional but Recommended)

Open Command Prompt as Administrator

Again, I pressed Win + X and selected Command Prompt (Admin) or Windows PowerShell (Admin).


Execute the Disable Command
powercfg /h off


Explanation:

This command disables hibernation, ensuring that the system fully shuts down without leaving the filesystem in a hibernated state.






D. Properly Shut Down Windows

Shutdown Windows Completely

I clicked on Start > Power > Shut down.
Important: I made sure not to use Restart, Sleep, or Hibernate options to ensure a clean shutdown.


Boot into Ubuntu

After shutting down, I started my computer and selected Ubuntu from the boot menu.


Verify Mounting in Ubuntu

Using GUI:

I opened the Files application and checked if the NTFS partitions were now accessible.


Using Terminal:
sudo mount -a


I then verified if the partitions were mounted successfully:
df -h | grep ntfs




Review dmesg Output:
sudo dmesg | grep -i ntfs


I ensured there were no longer any messages about the volume being dirty.





